# XConnect: Get contacts with at least 1 interaction between dates

Tags: xconnect

In a Sitecore 9.3 XP implementation, using XConnect, while trying to retrieve the contacts with at least 1 interaction between a period of time, the number of contacts is not matching what I see when compared to a SQL query.

XConnect query:

```
var contactsWithinDateXConnect = new List<Guid>();
var startDate = DateTime.Parse("2022-03-01");
var endDate = DateTime.Parse("2022-05-31");

using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    var myQuery = client.Contacts.Where(c =>
        c.Interactions.Any(i =>
            i.StartDateTime >= startDate.ToUniversalTime() 
            && i.EndDateTime <= endDate.ToUniversalTime()
        )
    );

    var myResults = myQuery.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(1000);
    while (myResults.MoveNext())
    {
        foreach (var contact in myResults.Current)
        {
            var contactId = contact.Id.Value;
            if (!contactsWithinDateXConnect.Any(p => p == contactId))
                contactsWithinDateXConnect.Add(contactId);
        }
    }
}
```

This will result in contactsWithinDateXConnect having only 2 contacts.

However, if I use a SQL query to retrieve the contacts from the Shard databases directly, the result will have much more contacts (45).

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ContactId]
FROM [Sitecore_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]
WHERE [StartDateTime] >= '2022-03-01' AND [StartDateTime] <= '2023-05-31'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT [ContactId]
FROM [Sitecore_Xdb.Collection.Shard1].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]
WHERE [StartDateTime] >= '2022-03-01' AND [StartDateTime] <= '2023-05-31'
```

Indeed the 2 contacts found by XConnect are present among the 45 contacts found with SQL, however, it looks like XConnect is missing lots of them.

Any clues on why that happens, steps to debug & potential fixes are welcome!

Comment: Have you tried to print out the SQL query from the linq expression and compare it with the union statement?

Comment: How can I do that? This Linq expression runs on XConnect

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237312/get-sql-query-from-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When retrieving contacts from XConnect, the sitecore API uses the xDB search index. By default the index is set to not include anonymous contacts.

What I suspect is happening in your example is that 43 of your contacts are anonymous, and only 2 contacts have been identified and have Isknown flag set to true.

If you join the result of your sql statement to the contats, then contactsidentifiers table you should be able to see the number of known contacts.

Alternatively, if in test environment you could update settings in xconnect to index anonymous. To do this:

Go to `sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml`
file on search indexer and update:

```
<IndexAnonymousContactData>true</IndexAnonymousContactData>
```

Then rebuild the index.

More info here https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html

Comment: This is exactly what's happening. Thanks!

Would it be a way to "bypass" the index and get anonymous contacts without indexing them to the search index? I assume it's not, but worth asking,

Comment: Not as far as im aware. I thnk it would definitely be a useful feature if it was possible.

Comment: Dean, I discovered if you use the SQL queries to retrieve the IDs, then you can still use the contactIds taken from SQL to get the contact using xConnect - the contact will be found normally.